# Ambiguity with [kconfig] and [kbuild]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

There are two tags [kbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kbuild) and [kconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kconfig).

The wiki entry for *kconfig* says that it is for a KDE configuration.  However, only a few question seems to deal with KDE.  The others are all to do with the Linux configuration system, which the tag *kbuild* is about.

My instinct is that the majority of people will use *kconfig* for Linux configuration or *menuconfig* type issues, which are present in different projects, but commonly associated with Linux kernel builds and configuration.

There are three questions of twelve in *kconfig* which should not be with *kbuild* questions (There were 13 as I just moved one).

- [Can kconfig language install on mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313051/can-kconfig-language-install-on-mac-os) - not sure?
- [Multiple config tabs in python plasmoid with kconfigxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723381/multiple-config-tabs-in-python-plasmoid-with-kconfigxt) - KDE based.
- [How to load default settings with kconfig on kdelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376698/how-to-load-default-settings-with-kconfig-on-kdelib) - KDE based.

I can manually retag, but I think the *kconfig* tag with just fill with more *kbuild* type questions.  I understand that *KDE Configuration* is a separate and valid topic, but 3 questions in 8 years seems a little under used and I think they could just be folded into the main *kde* tag or via a new *kde-kconfig* tag.

Should *kbuild* and *kconfig* be made synonyms or just manually retagged the *kbuild* related questions and leave the three *KDE* related questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved all of the current questions that are directly related to the Linux's *Kconfig* and variants (such as build root).  I also updated the *kconfig* tag wiki so people will hopefully post to the correct tags.